# how to implement null validation

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
set temp = "sunny45"

if [ - z $temp ]; then echo "empty" ; else echo "not empty" ; fi
```

The above code is giving  below error when i tried this code on unix terminal

if: Expression syntax.

Please suggest should i source any thing in file and what should ne the file name of this code present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whipe spaces around equal sign and between `-` and `z`, then enclose variable in double-quotes:

```
temp="sunny45"

if [ -z "$temp" ]; then echo "empty" ; else echo "not empty" ; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple syntax errors. Probably try with http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human help.

`set` will not set a regular variable. I'm guessing you want

```
temp="sunny45"
```

where you need to make sure there is no whitespace on either side of the equals sign.

The `-z` in the test similarly needs to be a single token, with no internal whitespace. You also need to [quote the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable).

```
if [ -z "$temp" ]; then
```